# Updating build number in version file before starting actual build and pushing back to origin in Jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Following is my Jenkins build job stages.
Build is triggerd by SCM polling for every 4 hours.
In stage2, push to origin step fails if origin has new changes since build workspace being pulled.

current workaround: I can do "`git pull --rebase`" in stage2 before doing "`git push origin`". But it will include new commit into build workspace which is acutally not present in Jenkins pipeline's "changes" integrated in the build list. It will create confusion on what changes are included in a build.

Can someone provide better solution for this ?

1. stage1: chekcout from Git
   **2. stage2: update build number in version file, commit and push to origin.**
2. stage3: do actual build
3. stage4: test and deploy build artifacts.

Comment: Why does step 1 have two stages in it?  This causes step 2 to be stage 3, and step 3 to be stage 4. That seems ... weird. But in general, Jenkins should not attempt to make Git commits. Build numbers, if they are separate from commit hash IDs, should not be committed at all.

Comment: If you want to be able to identify the build number a build package has, simply include the updated version file in the package. If you want to be able to identify in git repo the point where a particular build was made, tag it with the build number.